# Can I freeze already caramelized Mirepoix?

Tags: freezing, stock, vegetarian

I was wondering if I could batch cook enormous amounts of Mirepoix (finely diced carrots, onions, and celery) until they're a little caramelized and then freeze it in ice cube trays for various recipes later.

I've successfully done this with just caramelized onions, though I had to coat them in a decent amount of oil.

I was wondering why I haven't found anywhere on the internet of people talking about doing this with mirepoix, does it mess up the flavor or ruin it?

Comment: Not in answer to your question, but I also see caramelised onions, made in a slow cooker with hardly any oil. So long as I don't pack them too tightly into the container (when they form a solid block), they freeze well without additional oil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't frozen caramelized mirepoix, but I have frozen the closely related [sofrito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofrito), already caramelized. The results were fine... freezing and thawing caused some liquid to separate out, but once used in cooking it seemed the same as freshly cooked sofrito.

Comment: What do you include in your sofrito?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes you can](https://sprigandspoon.com/how-to-freeze-mirepoix/), but apparently you should freeze it without cooking it first.  I don't know why you wouldn't cook it, but I've reviewed 8 different online recipes and all of them freeze the mirepoix raw.  It's even [a commercial product](https://www.cascadianfarm.com/product/frozen-diced-onions-celery-carrots/).

Comment: Isn't that product frozen but raw? The picture and description look like it is, and that's what I've bought (though the local supermarkets all seem to have stopped selling it)

Comment: ... The recipe you link also says "no pre-cooking"

Comment: Interesting!  So, I cased online articles discussing freezing mirepoix, and 100% of them freeze it raw.  I can't find any sources that freeze it cooked.  That suggests that freezing it cooked is a bad idea, but I couldn't tell you why.

Comment: If I could get the frozen stuff at the moment, I'd cook a batch of that and try it.  I haven't tried lightly browned onions, only soft slowly caramelised ones, and not celery, though roasted carrots freeze.  I feel like it should work so long as you want the result to be soft.  I suspect the idea falls in between batch cooking and meal prepping, so purists in both camps don't do it.